# Gmail authentication requires phone verification

Tags: gmail, security

A group project I am involved in has a shared Gmail account for a while now. There is no single number associated with this account which I am aware of.

I was trying to log from another device than a usual one so Google asked me to prove I am human. Hence a SMS or phone call option ...Authenticating a user via SMS. This is not a two factor authentication.

Once in I was looking for a trace of my phone number so as to delete it. Where would Google store it with in the shared account if it does store it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If it was a "prove you're human" step, then they probably don't have the number stored at all. Presumably a bot isn't going to be able to act on an SMS message. If it's a "prove you're you" step, then something else is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... if it does store it

Presumably you did not have to enter your phone number during this authentication stage? So, it must already have been "stored"?

Or, if this was literally just a "prove you're human" step and you were required to enter your phone number, then I doubt that Google would store this phone number with the account. (?) Although I have not experienced this type of "prove you're human" validation. The usual Google anti-bot check these days is a "simple" checkbox (formerly a captcha).

To check your account:

1. Navigate to your Google Account:
   https://myaccount.google.com/
2. Your personal info - check the phone number
   https://myaccount.google.com/privacy#personalinfo

You should also check the "Security alerts settings", as this will show the phone number (entered above) and whether this is enabled:
https://security.google.com/settings/security/alerts